# PHP Redactor WYSIWYG no post value

Tags: php, jquery, redactor

I'm getting a really weird problem where the WYSIWYG editor redactor is not posting the values to the server.  Here is how I'm implementing it:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/shared/javascripts/redactor/redactor.css" />
<script src="/assets/shared/javascripts/redactor/redactor.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#redactor_content').redactor({
    imageUpload: '/upload/image/<?=$_GET['id']?>/',
    imageGetJson: '/upload/index/<?=$_GET['id']?>/'
    });
});
</script>

<textarea name="content" id="redactor_content"></textarea>
```

And I'm trying to retrieve the post value using `$_POST['content']`.

I thought it might be the older version of the jQuery library but if I use the demo scripts it works fine with jQuery 1.7.2.  I'm not seeing anything in the console and I checked it's not working in both Chrome and Firefox.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was some malformed HTML that was causing both Chrome and Firefox to automatically close the form tag early.  I moved the opening form tag further up and now see all post data from the WYSIWYG editor (redactor).  Hope this helps someone else.